# How to make multiple ajax calls more efficiently

Tags: jquery, ajax

Firstly, I am a total noob to ajax, and doing this for the first time!

I have a data table that I am updating using ajax, and have just got this working updating one row, which is working great.

Now I need to expand this to use multiple ajax calls to update multiple rows in the table, but this looks messy, and repeats lots of code where only the row ID will change each time.

NOTE: I can't update the whole table as one ajax call, because not all rows need updated, and not all cells in each row need updated. Some cells contain fixed information and never need updated. So I am only calling the cells that have changing data.

Is there a more efficient way to loop through multiple ajax calls, to call and update each row in my table?

My code just now is like this...

```
$.ajax({
 cache: false,
 url: 'updatetable.php',
 data: "rowid=1234",
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
  $('#row1234 .col3').html("" + data[0] + "");
  $('#row1234 .col4').html("" + data[1] + "");
  $('#row1234 .col6').html("" + data[2] + "");
 }
});

$.ajax({
 cache: false,
 url: 'updatetable.php',
 data: "rowid=2222",
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
  $('#row2222 .col3').html("" + data[0] + "");
  $('#row2222 .col4').html("" + data[1] + "");
  $('#row2222 .col6').html("" + data[2] + "");
 }
});

$.ajax({
 cache: false,
 url: 'updatetable.php',
 data: "rowid=3456",
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
  $('#row3456 .col3').html("" + data[0] + "");
  $('#row3456 .col4').html("" + data[1] + "");
  $('#row3456 .col6').html("" + data[2] + "");
 }
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about it

Comment: I don't want to repeat the same block of code many times. It is very messy. Only the row ID number changes each time. So is there a way to make these AJAX calls in a loop, to reduce the amount of repeated code?

Comment: can you please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please gather all Row ID and merge into Array and pass them to ajax and get all response from the ajax and display to the table**

```
<script>
     var array = new Array();
     array.push(row1_ID);
     array.push(row2_ID);
     array.push(row3_ID);
     var rowIDs = array.toString();
     $.ajax({
     cache: false,
     url: 'updatetable.php',
     data: {'row_ids':rowIDs},
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
         /* Here you will get all the data of each every row */
            $rowData = $.parseJSON(data);       
            $.each( obj, function(row_id, rowData ) {
                 $('#row'+row_id +' .col3').html("" + rowData[0] + "");
                 $('#row'+row_id +'.col4').html("" + rowData[1] + "");
                 $('#row'+row_id +' .col6').html("" + rowData[2] + ""); 
            });
     }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: No need to use `parseJSON()` when `dataType:'json'` is set. The data returned to callbacks will already be parsed

Answer (score 1):

As the only thing that changes is the `data` you send and the roe thats updated, you can put that in to an array and use a loop:

```js
['1234', '2222', '3456'].forEach(function(id) {
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: 'updatetable.php',
    data: { rowid: id },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $(`#row${id} .col3`).html(data[0]);
      $(`#row${id} .col4`).html(data[1]);
      $(`#row${id} .col6`).html(data[2]);
    }
  });
});
```

One thing to note, however, is that sending multiple AJAX requests in quick succession is not a very good idea as it can flood the server with requests if you have any decent number of concurrent users. It's much better practice to instead make a single call with *all* data included - in your case, the array of `rowid` values.